# Store array of String in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using realm in my iOS app. In my app, I have made an object file in which, there are some string variables and I have one array also in it. This is my `Object` class for realm,

```
class Reminder: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var done = false
  @objc dynamic var namesArray = [String]()
}
```

Now in my VC, I am passing an array to the `namesArray` of my `Object` class.

```
let names : [String] = ["Ali","Hammad","Hamza"]
let textFieldReminder = (alertVC.textFields?.first)! as UITextField
let reminderItem = Reminder()       // (8)
reminderItem.name = textFieldReminder.text!
reminderItem.done = false
reminderItem.namesArray = names

// We are adding the reminder to our database
try! self.realm.write({
            self.realm.add(reminderItem)
```

Now when I run the app, the application crashes with this error messages,

> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'namesArray' is declared as 'NSArray', which is not a
> ```
>
> supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be primitives,
>   NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or
>   subclasses of RLMObject. See
>   https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html for more
>   information.'

How can i store array of string in my realm db?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot store Swift **Array** to Realm store.  Instead of using **Array** you could make it `List<String>`. And you can use `append(objectsIn:)` method.

```
class Reminder: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var done = false
  let namesArray = List<String>()
}
```

Then, simply append new items to the list like this,

```
let names : [String] = ["Ali","Hammad","Hamza"]
let textFieldReminder = (alertVC.textFields?.first)! as UITextField

let reminderItem = Reminder()       // (8)
reminderItem.name = textFieldReminder.text!
reminderItem.done = false
reminderItem.append(objectsIn: names)
```

Comment: The app is crashing with this error, Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Reminder.namesArray' has been added." . @Sandeep

Comment: Well you changed the schema now. Remove the app from simulator and install it again and it should work fine.

Comment: @Hamza If this response was helpful, the author should receive an upvote.

Comment: sure bro . @Starsky

Comment: Thanks @AbuzarManzoor. Please upvote if it worked 