# How to add [String?] to realm model. (Should be @Persisted)

Tags: swift, realm

```
class RealmDataBaseClass: Object{
//...
    @Persisted var arrayOfCheckInDays: [String?] = []
//...
}
```

I need to add array of String? to realm, but it showing error: Generic struct 'Persisted' requires that '[String?]' conform to _Persistable

how to fix?

```
class RealmDataBaseClass: Object{
//...
    dynamic var arrayOfCheckInDays: [String?] = []
//...
}
```

If I do like this, arrayOfCheckInDays doesn't appear at model when I print it.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062272/store-array-of-string-in-realm?

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter, no quite. I need to save this array in memory. But it saves it temporary

Comment: have you tried adding @Persisted?

Comment: It's not clear what's being asked here. Realm has NO arrays, only Collections; Results, Lists etc. Also, non-managed properties do not need `@Persisted` as they are not persisted; that definition is specifically for Realm objects if you really mean 'in-memory' then those are not persisted. Non-managed objects can be mixed with managed objects freely within classes. Whatever was suggested 'works' but it's not clear what actually 'works'. e.g. `var myStringArray = [String]()` is perfectly valid and has no relation to Realm whereas `@Persisted var myStringList = List<String>()` is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a List instead of an array:
@Persisted var arrayOfCheckInDays: List<String?>

You can see supported Realm types here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/ Array is not a supported type.